# How to identify the coordinates of a specific block

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm creating a wave rush world where every night, enemies spawn from mob spawners and attack you. I found a cave system and placed mob spawners all over it, but now I need help to find all of them because I don't know the locations for all of them. Is there a command for this or something?

Comment: Do you just want to remove them? Then use `/fill … replace`.

Comment: No, just find them so I can go to all the locations and remove one.

Comment: This looks like another use of my block finder contraption that I made long ago in 1.8 or so. It doesn't work anymore in current versions, so you can't use that. I doubt that there is a simple way to do what you want then. Edit: It was also in Java edition, so completely different anyway.

Comment: Is there a way to do it in general? If not at least to find them, then to remove them all or something

Comment: Yes, removing is possible with `/fill`, as I said.

Comment: If you use the `fill` command, you would do `/fill [x y z of one corner] [x y z of corner across from first corner] air 0 replace [block to remove] 0`

Answer (score -1):

Technically speaking, there is a command to identify if a specific block is present at specific coordinates. It's [the `testforblock` comand](https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/testforblock_command.php):

> In Minecraft Xbox One Edition, the syntax to test whether a certain block is in a specific location is:
>
> ```
> /testforblock <position> <tileName> [dataValue]
> ```
>
> Definitions
>
> - position is the x y z coordinate to test.
> - tileName is name of the block to test for. (See Minecraft Item Names).
> - dataValue is optional. It is the variation of the block if more than one type exists for that tileName. To match on all data values, either omit this parameter or use a dataValue of -1.

While incredibly impractical for your use-case, it would be as simple as stepping through coordinates checking for `mob_spawner`:

```
testforblock 0 0 0 mob_spawner
```

Comment: uh... last I checked you can't execute commands on xbox

Comment: @DJshelfmushroom you have to enable it, but you can. That's what I primarily play on.

Comment: huh cool I didnt know tht